# Can seem to change highlight bar in menu selection

Tags: neovim

How can I change the highlight color of tab completion? I tried the below but it did not effect the highlight bar.

```
:hi PmenuSel ctermfg=white ctermbg=blue gui=bold guifg=white guibg=purple

:hi Pmenu ctermfg=white ctermbg=black gui=NONE guifg=white guibg=black
```

In this screen shot, it is hard to tell but the postMockSubject$ is highlighted

[image]

Comment: It seems to me that you are using a plugin that enrich the completion menu. I believe we should know which one in order to help you. Could you determine which plugin is responsable of the additional side window?

Comment: I believe you are correct, it is most likely the typescript plugin coc

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. There are probably some special highlighting groups for Coc that need to be set accordingly.